# IllegalStateException thrown when reading the vert.x http client response body

Tags: vert.x

I am getting the following error when I attempt to read the body from the http client response object. I don't get the exception all the time so I guess it's a threading issue related to the CompletableFuture. Any idea of what I am doing wrong? I use vert.x 3.8.1

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.checkEnded(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:134)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.endHandler(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:153)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.bodyHandler(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:193)
    at com.diagnostics.Response.body(Web.kt:116)
    at com.diagnostics.Response.bodyNow(Web.kt:111)
    at com.diagnostics.Response.bodyNow$default(Web.kt:110)
    at com.diagnostics.Main.postVerificationTest(Main.kt:73)
    at com.diagnostics.Main.main(Main.kt:52)
    at com.diagnostics.Main.main(Main.kt)
```

Code that throws the exception:

```
val response = client.get(requestUri = "/api/info").get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

val expectedStatus = 200
assertConditionOrExit(pvtLog, response.status == expectedStatus, "response status is ${response.status} expecting $expectedStatus")
val body = response.bodyNow()
assertConditionOrExit(pvtLog, body.isNotEmpty(), "body is empty expecting a non empty value")
```

The http client response object is created from the following code:

```
private fun request(
    method: HttpMethod,
    port: Int,
    host: String,
    requestUri: String
): CompletableFuture<Response> {
    val future = CompletableFuture<Response>()
    httpClient.request(method, port, host, requestUri)
        .exceptionHandler { future.completeExceptionally(it) }
        .handler { resp -> future.complete(Response(resp)) }
        .end()
    return future
}
```

And the body is retrieved...

```
fun bodyNow(timeout: Long = 10, unit: TimeUnit = SECONDS): String {
    return body().get(30000, SECONDS)
}

fun body(): CompletableFuture<String> {
    val future = CompletableFuture<String>()
    resp.bodyHandler { buff -> future.complete(buff.toString())}
    return future
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body()` function sets a `bodyHandler` **after** the `HttpClientRequest` handler has been invoked in the `request()` method.

So there is a chance that, while your main thread proceeds, the eventloop receives content and drops it. If content is small, the request could even end before the `bodyHandler` is set.

This is why you only see the exception from time to time.

If you want to set the `bodyHandler` later, you must pause the `HttpClientResponse`:

```
httpClient.request(method, port, host, requestUri)
    .exceptionHandler { future.completeExceptionally(it) }
    .handler { resp -> 
        resp.pause() // Pause the response
        future.complete(Response(resp))
    }
    .end()
```

Then resume it after setting the `bodyHandler`:

```
resp.bodyHandler { buff -> future.complete(buff.toString())}
resp.resume()
```

Comment: That makes sense. I will give it a go. Thanks @tsegismont!